# Disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on Safari

Tags: safari, ssl

Safari would disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 next year. I would like to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 before that, so I got the benefit right now. I [did it to my Firefox](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/turn-off-ssl-3-0-and-tls-1-0-in-your-browser/#FF), but I use Safari more. Is it possible to do it to Safari?

I care more about macOS but it would be helpful to see fix for iOS as well.

Comment: Note: I understand that some old site would break, and that’s the desired effect.

Comment: We will have to wait for others to chime in.  I am not seeing a way to do it in either MacOS or Safari.

Comment: @ThomasNelson That’s really sad…