# Make Safari on macOS reject insecure connections again

Tags: macos, safari, security, ssl

*Summary:*

I had opened an insecure website in Safari on macOS, which is now displayed  with the "Not Secure" warning in the address field. I would like to “reset“ Safari so that this (and other) insecure websites are blocked again.

*Details:*

- I had opened a website in Safari, which apparently uses an deprecated TLS protocol.
- Safari displayed a warning (reproduced here from a different computer):

[image]

- I decided to take the risk and clicked on “visit this website.”
- As expected, the website is displayed, with a red warning “Not Secure” in the address field.
- Now I would like to make Safari reject this (and other) insecure websites again.

*Things I tried:*

- Remove all website data in Safari, restart Safari, restart the computer.
- Opened the Keychain Access app and searched for a certificate which might have been added as trusted, but found none relate to this website.
- Search for “disable TLS” on this site, which only lead to [Disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/366085/30895), which does not solve my problem.
- Search for “safari disable tls 1.1” in the Internet, which lead to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250535567) and similar pages, which do not solve my problem either.

*Configuration:* Safari 15.3 on macOS Big Sur 11.6.3.

Comment: Did you try: Safari -> Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data…-> Remove All ?

Comment: @slartibartfast: Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem. Clicking on “visit this website” in the Safari TLS security alert stores an exception for that host in the Safari preferences. Apparently, this exception is *not* removed

- by a restart of Safari,
- by Safari -> Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data…-> Remove All,
- by restarting the computer,
- after some time.

However, the exception entry can be removed from the preferences file, for example with the [**PlistBuddy**](https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/PlistBuddy/) tool from the command line.

The full path to the Safari preferences file is

```
/Users/<userName>/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
```

The preference key is “allowedLegacyTLSHosts” and the value is a dictionary, mapping host names to dates.

First open a Terminal window, make sure that the current working directory is the home directory, and call PlistBuddy with the "Print" command:

```
% cd 
% /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist -c "Print :allowedLegacyTLSHosts:"
Dict {
    unsafe.host.net = Fri Feb 11 21:06:06 CET 2022
}
```

To remove the exception for “unsafe.host.net”, quit Safari and call PlistBuddy with the "Delete" command:

```
% cd 
% /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist -c "Delete :allowedLegacyTLSHosts:unsafe.host.net"
```

Check that the entry has been removed:

```
% cd 
% /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist -c "Print :allowedLegacyTLSHosts:"
Dict {
}
```

Now opening that page in Safari produces the “This Connection Is Not Private” alert again.

*Remarks:*

- I had updated my computer to macOS Monterey (12.2.1) in the meantime, therefore I do not know if this approach works in previous releases.
- Other/simpler solutions, perhaps without the need to execute complicated commands in the Terminal, are still welcome.